# Mask Text Input to Validate MM/YY jquery-mask-plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mask

Using `jquery-mask-plugin` I want to mask an input to only accept reasonable MM/YY

`$('#expDate').mask("99/99");` works but it allows for `55/66` which is not an acceptable month.

How can I make it so the first part of the mask is `<= 12`

Comment: How about a regex, perhaps something like this: ((0[1-9]|1[0-2])/(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this with just the jquery-mask plugin. As you noted, it only masks out certain TYPES of inputs, such as numbers (in general), letters, symbols, etc. It does not perform data validation (which is what you're asking for.

You can write a simple jQuery function that runs onblur, etc that rejects invalid combinations:

```
$('#expDate').blur(function() {
  let val = $(this).val();
  if (val.indexOf('/') > 0)
    {
      let first = val.split('/')[0]; 
      if (first > 12)  $(this).val('');
    }   
});
```

Alternatively, you can use the great jQuery Validate plugin:
https://jqueryvalidation.org/

To be clear, you want data validation beyond just basic input masking.

Comment: Correct I am mainly concerned with the mask but it would be nice to have validation as well. The blur works good enough, I have additional validation that verifies input. So if it is cleared like your method does, my validation won't let it submit. Thanks!